# Effiecient Algorithm for Finding if a Very Big Number is Divisible by 7

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, division

So this was a question on one of the challenges I came across in an online competition, a few days ago.

**Question:**

Accept two inputs.

1. A big number of ***N*** digits,
2. The number of questions ***Q*** to be asked.

In each of the question, you have to find if the number formed by the string between indices ***L***<sub>***i***</sub> and ***R***<sub>***i***</sub> is divisible by 7 or not.

**Input:**

First line contains the number consisting on ***N*** digits. Next line contains ***Q***, denoting the number of questions. Each of the next **Q** lines contains 2 integers ***L***<sub>***i***</sub> and ***R***<sub>***i***</sub>.

**Output:**

For each question, print "YES" or "NO", if the number formed by the string between indices ***L***<sub>***i***</sub> and ***R***<sub>***i***</sub> is divisible by 7.

**Constraints:**

1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>

1 ≤ Q ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>

1 ≤ L<sub>i</sub>, R<sub>i</sub> ≤ N

**Sample Input:**

357753 
3 
1  2 
2  3 
4  4

**Sample Output:**

YES 
NO 
YES

**Explanation:**

For the first query, number will be 35 which is clearly divisible by 7.

---

***Time Limit:*** 1.0 sec for each input file.

***Memory Limit:*** 256 MB

***Source Limit:*** 1024 KB

---

**My Approach:**

Now according to the constraints, the maximum length of the number i.e. **N** can be upto ***10***<sup>***5***</sup>. This big a number cannot be fitted into a numeric data structure and I am pretty sure thats not the efficient way to go about it.

**First Try:**

I thought of this algorithm to apply the generic rules of division to each individual digit of the number. This would work to check divisibility amongst any two numbers, in linear time, i.e. **O(N)**.

```
static String isDivisibleBy(String theIndexedNumber, int divisiblityNo){

    int moduloValue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < theIndexedNumber.length(); i++){

        moduloValue = moduloValue * 10;
        moduloValue += Character.getNumericValue(theIndexedNumber.charAt(i));
        moduloValue %= divisiblityNo;
    }

    if(moduloValue == 0){
        return "YES";
    } else{
        return "NO";
    }

}
```

But in this case, the algorithm has to also loop through all the values of **Q**, which can also be upto ***10***<sup>***5***</sup>.

Therefore, the time taken to solve the problem becomes **O(Q.N)** which can also be considered as **Quadratic time**. Hence, this crossed the given time limit and was **not efficient.**

**Second Try:**

After that didn't work, I tried searching for a **divisibility rule of 7**. All the ones I found, involved calculations based on each individual digit of the number. Hence, that would again result in a Linear time algorithm. And hence, combined with the number of Questions, it would amount to **Quadratic Time, i.e. O(Q.N)**

I did find one algorithm named **Pohlman–Mass method of divisibility by 7**, which suggested

> Using quick alternating additions and subtractions: 
>   42,341,530
>   -> 530 − 341 = 189 + 42 = 231 -> 23 − (1×2) = 21  YES

But all that did was, make the time 1/3rd Q.N, which didn't help much.

---

Am I missing something here? Can anyone help me find a way to solve this efficiently?

Also, is there a chance this is a **Dynamic Programming problem?**

Comment: You first attempt can perform the operation as you read it. This way the memory is `O(1)` and the CPU is `O(N)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, the algorithm has Linear Time. But in this case, the the solution has to be calculated for Q questions where Q could be anything below 100000. So if i call the function Q times, its complexity turns out to be O(Q.N), which is as good as quadratic time.

Comment: Do you want to know if any range of digits forms a number divisible by 7?

Comment: The range has to be between indexes L(i) and R(i)  which is specified in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to go through this problem.

**1: Dynamic Programming Approach**
Let the input be array of digits `A[N]`.
Let `N[L,R]` be number formed by digits `L to R`.
Let another array be `M[N]` where `M[i] = N[1,i] mod 7`.
So `M[i+1] = ((M[i] * 10) mod 7 + A[i+1] mod 7) mod 7`
Pre-calculate array `M`.

Now consider the expression.
`N[1,R] = N[1,L-1] *` 10<sup>R-L+1</sup> `+ N[L,R]`
 `implies (N[1,R] mod 7) = (N[1,L-1] mod 7 *` (10<sup>R-L+1</sup>`mod 7)) + (N[L,R] mod 7)`
    `implies N[L,R] mod 7 = (M[R] - M[L-1] *` (10<sup>R-L+1</sup> `mod 7)) mod 7`

`N[L,R] mod 7` gives your answer and can be calculated in `O(1)` as all values on right of expression are already there.
For 10<sup>R-L+1</sup> `mod 7`, you can pre-calculate modulo 7 for all powers of 10.

Time Complexity :
Precalculation `O(N)`
Overall `O(Q) + O(N)`

**2: Divide and Conquer Approach**
Its a [segment tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/) solution.
On each tree node you store the mod 7 for the number formed by digits in that node.
And the expression given in first approach can be used to find the mod 7 of parent by combining the mod 7 values of two children.
The time complexity of this solution will be `O(Q log N) + O(N log N)`

Comment: @Shashwat Kumar : is the array index starts from 0 or 1 ? if it is 0, how `M[0]` can be derived with the above algo ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to be able to to calculate the mod 7 of any digits given the mod of the number at any point.

What you can do is to;

- record the modulo at each point O(N) for time and space. Uses up to 100 KB of memory.
- take the modulo at the two points and determine how much subtracting the digits before the start would make e.g.  O(N) time and space (once not per loop)

e.g. between 2 and 3 inclusive

```
357 % 7 = 0
3 % 7 = 3 and 300 % 7 = 6 (the distance between the start and end)
```

and 0 != 6 so the number is not a multiple of 7.

between 4 and 4 inclusive

```
3577 % 7 == 0
357 % 7 = 0 and 0 * 10 % 7 = 0
```

as 0 == 0 it is a multiple of 7.

Comment: I guess this would help in optimising the memory space. But the problem I had was the time. 

I am sorry I am having a little difficulty to understand how this would reduce the time, as according to this, the value of mod will have to be calculated for each individual digit, which would make it O(N) for time.

Now I have to run this for Q test cases, which would make it O(Q.N), where both Q and N are big numbers.

Comment: @AnmolMahatpurkar you can calculate mod 7 for numbers that are single digits multiplied by a power of 10 in O(1) using the 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, ... trick described on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_7) wikipedia page

Comment: @AnmolMahatpurkar It's `O(N + Q)` as the time to handle any individual query is `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You first build a list of digits modulo 7 for each number starting with 0 offset (like in your case, 0%7, 3%7, 35%7, 357%7...) then for each case of (a,b) grab digits[a-1] and digits[b], then multiply digits[b] by 1-3-2-6-4-5 sequence of 10^X modulo 7 defined by `(1+b-a)%6` and compare. If these are equal, return YES, otherwise return NO. A pseudocode:

```
readString(big);
Array a=[0]; // initial value
Array tens=[1,3,2,6,4,5]; // quick multiplier lookup table
int d=0;
int l=big.length;
for (int i=0;i<l;i++) {
    int c=((int)big[i])-48; // '0' -> 0, and "big" has characters
    d=(3*d+c)%7;
    a.push(d); // add to tail
}
readInt(q);
for (i=0;i<q;i++) {
    readInt(li);
    readInt(ri); // get question
    int left=(a[li-1]*tens[(1+ri-li)%6])%7;
    if (left==a[ri]) print("YES"); else print("NO");
}
```

A test example:

```
247761901
1
5 9
```

61901 % 7=0. Calculating:

```
a = [0 2 3 2 6 3 3 4 5 2]
li = 5
ri = 9
left=(a[5-1]*tens[(1+9-5)%6])%7 = (6*5)%7 = 30%7 = 2
a[ri]=2
Answer: YES
```